# Unable to get an instance of ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

I am trying to get some data from a website and load it into my app.
The app has 1 MainActivity and 3 fragments and uses ViewBinding.

Unfortunately I can not create a instance of viewmodel in the 1st Fragment.
I already searched stackoverflow and the internet (a lot) but I somehow can not get all the solutions given working.

I get the exception on **materialViewModel.getMaterials().observe** in the HomeFragment.

Any help is highly appreciated.

My HomeFragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private MaterialViewModel materialViewModel;
    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    ArrayList<MaterialModel> posts;

    public HomeFragment() {
        
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        materialViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(MaterialViewModel.class);

        initializeRecyclerView();
        getPosts();

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    private void initializeRecyclerView() {

        posts = new ArrayList<>();
        binding.rvMain.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

    private void getPosts() {

        materialViewModel.getMaterials().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<MaterialModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MaterialModel> posts) {
                binding.rvMain.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter((ArrayList<MaterialModel>) posts));
            }
        });
        getIsLoaded();
    }

    public void getIsLoaded(){

        materialViewModel.getIsLoaded().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
                if (aBoolean == true){
                    //activityMainBinding.progressBarID.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.w("PAR-LOADED ", "DATA IS LOADED");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

My MaterialViewmodel:

```
public class MaterialViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private MutableLiveData<List<MaterialModel>> matts;
    private MaterialRepository materialRepository;

    public MaterialViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        materialRepository = new MaterialRepository(application);
    }
    public void init() {

        if (this.matts == null) {
            matts = materialRepository.getAllMaterials();
        }
    }
    public LiveData<List<MaterialModel>> getMaterials() {
        return this.matts;
    }
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> getIsLoaded() {
        return materialRepository.dataIsLoaded;
    }
}
```

My MaterialRepository:

```
public class MaterialRepository {

    API_Service service;
    private String posts;
    ArrayList<String> arrayLiNames = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayLiLinks = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<MaterialModel> materialData = new ArrayList<>();
    public MutableLiveData<List<MaterialModel>> mattis;
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> dataIsLoaded;

    public MaterialRepository(Application application) {
        super();

        service = RetrofitClass.getClient(application).create(API_Service.class);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<MaterialModel>> getAllMaterials() {

        Call<List<MaterialModel>> postResponseCall = service.getMaterials();

        postResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<MaterialModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<MaterialModel>> call, Response<List<MaterialModel>> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    Log.w("PAR-RESPONSE-CODE ", String.valueOf(response.code()));
                    posts = String.valueOf(response.body());
                    //new MyTask().execute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<MaterialModel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
        return mattis;
    }

private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<MaterialModel>> {
...
@Override
        protected List<MaterialModel> doInBackground(Void... params) {
       @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<MaterialModel> result) {

            mattis.setValue(result);
            dataIsLoaded.setValue(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you remember to initialize viewModel in your Activity? Also, observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),... instead of observe(getActivity(),...

Comment: Hi Angel Koh, yes I initialzed viewmodel in MainActivity: 
MaterialViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MaterialViewModel.class);
model.init();
But still same error, also with observe(getViewLifecycleOwner() instead of getActivity.

Comment: your  public MutableLiveData<List<MaterialModel>> mattis;  in the repository was never initialized. it's always null.

Comment: Thx Angel that was it but nothing visible in the apps recyclerview.